# Codeigniter phpmail > Google SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone help me "migrate" this form to G SMTP instead of PHP? You can see what I tried below but I am not getting it to work. I tried googling and search throughout libraries but without success. Does anyone know what is wrong with it? Thanks in advance!

My current script looks like this:

```
if (count($email_body) > 0)
            {
                $new_password = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),7);
                $this->email->from('email@email.com', 'Email - New Password');
                $this->email->to($choosenuser[0]->email);
                $parentss = array("[[firstname]]", "[[lastname]]", "[[new_pass]]", "[[base_url]]");
                $words   = array($choosenuser[0]->firstname, $choosenuser[0]->lastname, $new_password, base_url());
                $subject = str_replace($parentss, $words, $email_body[0]->subject);
                $this->email->subject($subject);
                $parentss = array("[[firstname]]", "[[lastname]]", "[[new_pass]]", "[[base_url]]");
                $words   = array($choosenuser[0]->firstname, $choosenuser[0]->lastname, $new_password, base_url());
                $text_obavestenja = str_replace($parentss, $words, $email_body[0]->tekst);
                if ($this->input->post('type') == 'trainer')
                {
                    $this->baza_model->izmeni_slog_array('lag_users', Array('id' => $choosenuser[0]->id), Array('password' => md5($new_password)));
                }else{
                    $this->baza_model->izmeni_slog_array('lag_challenge_users', Array('id' => $choosenuser[0]->id), Array('password' => md5($new_password)));
                }

                $this->email->message($text_obavestenja);
                $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                $this->email->send();
                //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }else{
                redirect('front/message/e-mail-message-missing', 'refresh');
            }
            redirect('front/message/passwordset/', 'refresh');
```

What I tried:

```
if (count($email_body) > 0)
            {
                $config = Array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'smtp_user' => $this->config->item("user", "EMAIL"),
                    'smtp_pass' => $this->config->item("pass", "Password"),
                    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
                 );
                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $new_password = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),7);
                $this->email->from('<' . $this->config->item("email", "email_from") . '>', $this->config->item("name", "email_from"));
                $this->email->to($this->config->item($choosenuser[0]->email));
                $parentss = array("[[firstname]]", "[[lastname]]", "[[new_pass]]", "[[base_url]]");
                $words   = array($choosenuser[0]->firstname, $choosenuser[0]->lastname, $new_password, base_url());
                $subject = str_replace($parentss, $words, $email_body[0]->subject);
                $this->email->subject($subject);
                $parentss = array("[[firstname]]", "[[lastname]]", "[[new_pass]]", "[[base_url]]");
                $words   = array($choosenuser[0]->firstname, $choosenuser[0]->lastname, $new_password, base_url());
                $text_obavestenja = str_replace($parentss, $words, $email_body[0]->tekst);
                if ($this->input->post('type') == 'trainer')
                {
                    $this->baza_model->izmeni_slog_array('lag_users', Array('id' => $choosenuser[0]->id), Array('password' => md5($new_password)));
                }else{
                    $this->baza_model->izmeni_slog_array('lag_challenge_users', Array('id' => $choosenuser[0]->id), Array('password' => md5($new_password)));
                }

                $this->email->message($text_obavestenja);
                $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                $this->email->send();
                //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }else{
                redirect('front/message/e-mail-message-missing', 'refresh');
            }
            redirect('front/message/passwordset/', 'refresh');
```

When I put debugger on nothing shows. Logs are empty.

Comment: You need to pass `FALSE` to the `send()` method if you want to use the `print_debugger()`

Comment: Mine works and is similar, are you sure `$this->config->item("user", "EMAIL")` is all UPPER case.  In otherwords are you sure your config stuff is what you think it is.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks, what I tried is hardcoding the email, but that didn't work neither, so I am not sure.

Comment: I would say to write a simplified test email, then you can rule out other issues.  It could be an issue with SSL, Firewall, network.  Many many things can go wrong with emails.

Comment: Are you sending the email to the same account that is used for the SMTP connection?  Because it wont work..  Well at least that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even when all of your Google SMTP connection settings are correct, you still need to tell Google to trust your app:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

In my CodeIgniter app, the only difference is that you are using ssl://smtp.googlemail.com and I am using ssl://smtp.gmail.com . This is why I think your issue is that you need to tell Google to trust the app.